# Using PECL to install extensions on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, pear, pecl

I've been trying to install some PECL extensions on my laptop, but I've ran into a few problems. Whenever I run pecl install whatever from the command line I get a message saying ".\php.exe appears to have a suffix .exe, but config variable php". It seems like PECL is using PEAR to perform installations. I checked and php_suffix is located in the files PEAR_Config.php and PEAR_Builder.php, but I'm not sure what to do with it in there.

Any ideas on how to fix this or workarounds? Unfortunately the pecl4win seems to be down, and http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ the site I usually go to for the .dll's has outdated versions for the version of PHP I'm using (5.3.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know the specifics, but at least I can point you in the right direction  To use pecl on windows, you need to setup Visual Studio c/c++ or MingW32 c/c++ and then configure pecl to use either compiler for building the requested extensions.

Unlike pear packages, pecl packages are PHP c extensions that needed to be compiled against your local PHP install.

Update

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild  A mostly friendly wiki page on setting up a windows box for building PHP from source.  Looks like you need to build the interpreter and support libraries before you can get pecl working.